# can't find variable: createDrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implement drawer navigation in my app. I found this website (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html) that gives a code example of implementation however when I run it it says

> can't find variable: createDrawerNavigator.

So that means there is a missing import. However, I cannot seem to find the right one for `createDrawerNavigator`. Wanted to know if anyone could help me fix this! Pretty new to React Native.

```
class MyHomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        drawerLabel: 'Home',
        drawerIcon: ({
            tintColor
        }) => ( <
            Image source = {
                require('./chats-icon.png')
            }
            style = {
                [styles.icon, {
                    tintColor: tintColor
                }]
            }
            />
        ),
    };

    render() {
        return ( <
            Button onPress = {
                () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Notifications')
            }
            title = "Go to notifications" /
            >
        );
    }
}

class MyNotificationsScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        drawerLabel: 'Notifications',
        drawerIcon: ({
            tintColor
        }) => ( <
            Image source = {
                require('./notif-icon.png')
            }
            style = {
                [styles.icon, {
                    tintColor: tintColor
                }]
            }
            />
        ),
    };

    render() {
        return ( <
            Button onPress = {
                () => this.props.navigation.goBack()
            }
            title = "Go back home" /
            >
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    icon: {
        width: 24,
        height: 24,
    },
});

const MyApp = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: MyHomeScreen,
    },
    Notifications: {
        screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
    },
});
```

Comment: `import { createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";`, you can import it like this

Comment: createDrawerNavigator is now shifted to 'react-navigation-drawer' from 'react-navigation' in latest versions of npm and react
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

Answer (score 5):

Every sub component you use, first you have to import it:
As [Pritish Vaidva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950769/cant-find-variable-createdrawernavigator#comments-51950769) mentioned you have to add

```
import { createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
```

at the head of your file.

Answer (score 0):

createDrawerNavigator is now shifted to 'react-navigation-drawer' from 'react-navigation' in latest versions of npm and react
Use Below Code

`import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';`